# Error in Slim library file NotFound.php that I cannot diagnose

Tags: php, slim

I have an app online that uses slim framework.  The site seems to be working fine but when I check the error log I am getting the below.

```
[Mon Apr 17 13:26:45.349695 2017] [:error] [pid 30816] [client xx.xxx.xx.133:39856] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/Sites/appName/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/NotFound.php on line 80
[Mon Apr 17 13:26:45.349755 2017] [:error] [pid 30816] [client xx.xxx.xx.133:39856] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: output in /var/www/Sites/appName/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/NotFound.php on line 61
[Wed Apr 19 22:14:32.271000 2017] [:error] [pid 13509] [client xx.xxx.xx.251:59585] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/Sites/appName/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/NotFound.php on line 80
[Wed Apr 19 22:14:32.271546 2017] [:error] [pid 13509] [client xx.xxx.xx.251:59585] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: output in /var/www/Sites/appName/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/NotFound.php on line 61
[Thu Apr 20 15:07:51.858254 2017] [:error] [pid 16996] [client xx.xxx.xx.61:37389] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/Sites/appName/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/NotFound.php on line 80
[Thu Apr 20 15:07:51.858844 2017] [:error] [pid 16996] [client xx.xxx.xx.61:37389] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: output in /var/www/Sites/appName/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/NotFound.php on line 61
[Fri Apr 21 10:27:05.650765 2017] [:error] [pid 20800] [client xx.xxx.xx.224:49737] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/Sites/appName/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/NotFound.php on line 80
[Fri Apr 21 10:27:05.651262 2017] [:error] [pid 20800] [client xx.xxx.xx.224:49737] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: output in /var/www/Sites/appName/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/NotFound.php on line 61
[Sat Apr 22 14:27:29.531275 2017] [:error] [pid 25129] [client xx.xxx.xx.62:59309] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/Sites/appName/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/NotFound.php on line 80
[Sat Apr 22 14:27:29.531323 2017] [:error] [pid 25129] [client xx.xxx.xx.62:59309] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: output in /var/www/Sites/appName/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/NotFound.php on line 61
```

I have tried to diagnose this myself but have not got very far at all.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to try to find the cause of these two errors?

Comment: Are you sure that slim is installed correctly? Try deleting the `vendor` and installing anew.

Answer (score 0):

[Line 80](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Handlers/NotFound.php#L80) of `NotFound.php` is a closing brace.

Therefore, I surmise that you don't have the latest version of Slim 3 installed, so please start by updating to the latest version.